# How to make size of Emacs frame persistent?

Tags: frames, microsoft-windows, customize, start-up

When I start Emacs (by clicking on a desktop icon), its frame is too big for the screen, so the mode-line/mini-buffer area is not visible.

It's not difficult to resize and reposition the frame, but it is irritating to have to do this every time one starts Emacs.

How can I preserve the size of the Emacs window across sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @Drew states.
I use this:

```
(defconst frame-default-top      0  "The 'top'  position property of a frame.")
(defconst frame-default-left     0  "The 'left' position property of a frame.")
(defconst frame-default-height  60  "The default frame height.")
(defconst frame-default-width  188  "The default frame width.")

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'left   frame-default-left))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'top    frame-default-top))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'height frame-default-height))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist (cons 'width  frame-default-width))
```

If you want only the initial frame use initial-frame-alist. I set both which is probably overkill.

```
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist (cons 'left   frame-default-left))
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist (cons 'top    frame-default-top))
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist (cons 'height frame-default-height))
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist (cons 'width  frame-default-width))
```

Answer (score 3):

Customize option `default-frame-alist`, in particular by providing a helpful value for frame parameter `height`:

```
M-x customize-option RET default-frame-alist RET
```

Be sure to save your changes to the value.

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Initial Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html) and [Size Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html).

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more concise version:

  `;; Set Frame width/height
  (setq default-frame-alist
        '((top . 25) (left . 275) (width . 105) (height . 60)))`

This makes the frame centered and approximately 2/3 of a 13inch laptop screen.