# Open new frame such that they fit one third of the screen

Tags: frames

I use `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . fullheight))` for having the new frames as tall as the screen.
How can I tell emacs to make the new frames as large as one third of the screen width?

Comment: You are interested in `display-pixel-width` and `display-pixel-height`, and just some basic division.  See also an example of feature request 21415 that is built-in to Emacs 25 to specify exact pixel height/width when creating a frame:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17354/2287

Comment: This will allow you to specify position, height and width: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31058/how-to-make-size-of-emacs-frame-persistent/31063#31063