# Storing position for initial frame

Tags: frames

I have the following code to store the position where to put the initial frame (`fxpos` and `fypos`).

My problem is that when I run a new emacs session, the `defcustom` commands are resetting the values back to `8`.  What can I do to avoid this?

```
(defgroup frame-pos nil
  "Set position of frame."
  :group 'convenience)

(defcustom fxpos 8
  "X position of initial frame."
  :type 'integer
  :group 'frame-pos)

(defcustom fypos 8
  "Y position of initial frame."
  :type 'integer
  :group 'frame-pos)

(defun frame-shift (frame)

  (let* ( (lft (car (frame-position)))
          (top (cdr (frame-position)))
          (wdt (frame-outer-width frame))
          (hgt (frame-outer-height frame))
          (fxmid (+ lft (/ wdt 2)))
          (fymid (+ top (/ hgt 2)))
          (mgm (cdr (assq 'geometry (frame-monitor-attributes frame))))
          (mxmid (+ (nth 0 mgm) (/ (nth 2 mgm) 2)))
          (mymid (+ (nth 1 mgm) (/ (nth 3 mgm) 2)))
          (nlft (+ lft (- mxmid fxmid)))
          (ntop (+ top (- mymid fymid))) )

    (custom-declare-variable 'fxpos nlft)
    (custom-declare-variable 'fypos ntop)))
```

Comment: The only way for emacs sessions to communicate is through the file system: save the settings to a file in the old session and read them in from the file in the new session.

Comment: I want emacs to display as usual when the values are not set.  Emacs decides where to put the initial frame.  Unless the user decides to call the function that computes a centered position.

Comment: I thought the way to save options in emacs is through defcustom.

Comment: The way for users to set customisation is through `defcustom`.  That that involve storing in a file system as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make size of Emacs frame persistent?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31058/how-to-make-size-of-emacs-frame-persistent)

Comment: No, although I understand the solution, I have been working on making the process automatic.  The values would be set by the user by calling a function that computes the position so that the frame is centered on the screen.

Comment: Although the other question gives a solution, one has to put the values in the elisp file.  But, I would like that users be able to set the values by calling a customisation routine, without them having to dabble in elisp.  Furthermore, the values for `top` and `left` are hardwired to `25` and `275`.  If users use the package, the values would be hardwired for them as well.  Thusly, things wight not show correctly for different sizes and configuration of screens they use.

Answer (score 0):

I vote to close the question as a duplicate. But if others don't also vote that way then here's the answer: `initial-frame-alist`.

> `initial-frame-alist` is a variable defined in `frame.el`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Alist of parameters for the initial X window frame.
>
> You can set this in your init file; for example,
>
> ```
> (setq initial-frame-alist
>       '((top . 1) (left . 1) (width . 80) (height . 55)))
> ```
>
> Parameters specified here supersede the values given in
> `default-frame-alist`.
>
> If the value calls for a frame without a minibuffer, and you have
> not created a minibuffer frame on your own, a minibuffer frame is
> created according to `minibuffer-frame-alist`.
>
> You can specify geometry-related options for just the initial
> frame by setting this variable in your init file; however, they
> won’t take effect until Emacs reads your init file, which happens
> after creating the initial frame.  If you want the initial frame
> to have the proper geometry as soon as it appears, you need to
> use this three-step process:
>
> - Specify X resources to give the geometry you want.
> - Set `default-frame-alist` to override these options so that they
>   don’t affect subsequent frames.
> - Set `initial-frame-alist` in a way that matches the X resources,
>   to override what you put in `default-frame-alist`.
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 24.1.

Comment: I am really struggling with this.  Here one is hardwiring the values, so that every time one calls emacs, the initial frame uses the hardwired values.  Thus, it is not possible for the user to call a function that determines the position of the frame, and then be able to store them for future sessions in variables.

Comment: Chicken, meet the egg...